# Android Studio 0.3.2: gradle compile problems

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

I just updated `Android Studio` to version `0.3.2`. My project uses Gradle version 1.8.
On the picture below you can see that it is configured in gradle and `Android Studio` resolver `http-async` package but gradle fails with `Gradle: package com.loopj.android.http does not exist`

I tried already

1. to remove `android-async-http` and adding it as Library again,
2. to include `fileTree(...)` in gradle configuration file,
3. Rebuilt project but nothing helped

Though if absolute path is set gradle works just fine.

[image]

### Gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:13.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36'

    compile files("libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar")
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to move the libs folder at the same level of src folder.

Comment: It didn't help though if absolute path is set gradle works just fine. But other people also work on the project.

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio have just released 0.3.7, which claims to have solved a lot of gradle issues such as adding .jar libraries

http://tools.android.com/recent

Hopefully this will help you!